# project workspace-how to import class from other projects ios

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have added two projects in xcode workspace., set scheme correctly.Is it possible to include or create subclasses of one project in other? Like, I have a class `coreViewController.swift` which is subclass of  `UIViewController` in one project. I would like to create a class say,  exampleViewController in second project which is a subclass of `CoreViewController.swift`?

Answer (score 0):

Although I would not do it, it's possible. Just chose *File > add file* and navigate to the class you want to add to your project. Deselect the copy option, done.

But I would suggest to choose a different approach and remove the class(es) you use in both projects out of both into a separate repository (ie. a framework, git externals, ...)